# Double maxsize in .net

Tags: c#

I saw double max size is : -1.79769313486232e308 to 1.79769313486232e308

But when i tried setting :

```
double bla = 99999999999999999999;
```

It says the number is too big.

Is double really that big? (e308).

Answer (score 6):

You need to add `d` to the end of the number to specify that it's a double.

```
double bla = 99999999999999999999d;
```

Without the `d` suffix, it's actually a constant *integer* (or would be, if it wasn't out of integer range) which is then cast to double.

Also note that because of [floating point precision](http://floating-point-gui.de/), the number you get back is actually `1E20` or `100000000000000000000`.

If you actually want to work with integers in that range, you should look at using [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) instead.

Comment: @omriman12 Take note that you will loose precision. You can have only 15 digits without loosing precision.

Answer (score 1):

At least one thing - 99999999999999999999 is not a double constant. Make it

99999999999999999999.0

and it should work.

http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpNumericLiterals.aspx

has more insformation on all numeric literals.